# How to create js object with php (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, algolia

I create some datasets to upload in Algolia.

For the price field, I create an array, and then, I convert it with json_encode to an json object.

In the database, the string looks like:

```
{"CH":{"currency":"CHF","value":21.900000000000002},"DE":{"currency":"EUR","value":16.8}}
```

When I upload the data to Algolia, there the data are stored like:

```
 "{\"CH\":{\"currency\":\"CHF\",\"value\":19.900000000000002},\"DE\":{\"currency\":\"EUR\",\"value\":15.3}}",
```

But finally, I need something like this:

```
{
    "CH": {
      "currency": "CHF",
      "value": 99
    },
    "DE": {
      "currency": "EUR",
      "value": 76
    }
  },
```

Is this a problem from Algolia? Or do I have to transform the string in another way?

From my point of view, the first string (from my db) is ok. But why this is uploaded with `"` at the beginning and the end of the string?

Comment: How do you upload to Algolia ?

Comment: with ` use Searchable;` it means, automatically when I change the record

Comment: Somehow Algolia is taking your data as string. You have to figure it out why it is doing so.

Comment: If I do it with postman, everything works well